# How do I add space between post titles in the Post Navigation Widget in Wordpress (ideally with some CSS)?

Tags: css, wordpress, padding, elementor

I am new to WordPress and website building in general. I can't add space between the post titles in the post navigation widget at the bottom of my posts. The titles meet at the center and it's confusing to read. Ideally, I would love to be able to display the title in multiple lines, but I would be okay with just having some space between them and having them disappear into ellipses.

![Here is a pic of what it looks like right now.][1]

Ideally, I would like to change this problem using CSS, though I am happy to learn how to do it with other code if that's not possible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the CSS code I found by inspecting the page:

```
element.style {
}
.elementor-kit-1 {
--e-global-color-primary: #FFFFFF;
--e-global-color-secondary: #FD3A97;
--e-global-color-text: #4A4848;
--e-global-color-accent: #FDB589;
--e-global-color-ac96d9d: #999999;
--e-global-typography-primary-font-family: "Calibri Light";
--e-global-typography-primary-font-weight: 600;
--e-global-typography-secondary-font-family: "Roboto Slab";
--e-global-typography-secondary-font-weight: 400;
--e-global-typography-text-font-family: "Roboto";
--e-global-typography-text-font-weight: 400;
--e-global-typography-accent-font-family: "Roboto";
--e-global-typography-accent-font-weight: 500;
}
body, .site-title {
font-family: Nunito, var(--nv-fallback-ff);
}
body {
font-size: 16px;
}
body {
font-family: Graphik,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,var(-- 
nv-fallback-ff);
color: var(--nv-text-color);
line-height: 1.68421;
overflow-x: hidden;
direction: ltr;
background-color: var(--nv-site-bg);
}
.nv-html-content p, blockquote, body, dd, dl, dt, fieldset, figure, 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, html, iframe, legend, li, ol, p, pre, 
textarea, ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
*, :after, :before {
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
body {
display: block;
margin: 8px;
}
:root {
--e-global-color-nvprimaryaccent: #fd3a97;
--e-global-color-nvsecondaryaccent: #fdb589;
--e-global-color-nvsitebg: #fff;
--e-global-color-nvlightbg: #ededed;
--e-global-color-nvdarkbg: #14171c;
--e-global-color-nvtextcolor: #393939;
--e-global-color-nvtextdarkbg: #fff;
--e-global-color-nvc1: #f5e6de;
--e-global-color-nvc2: #4a4848;
}
:root {
--nv-primary-accent: #fd3a97;
--nv-secondary-accent: #fdb589;
--nv-site-bg: #fff;
--nv-light-bg: #ededed;
--nv-dark-bg: #14171c;
--nv-text-color: #393939;
--nv-text-dark-bg: #fff;
--nv-c-1: #f5e6de;
--nv-c-2: #4a4848;
--nv-fallback-ff: Arial , Helvetica , sans-serif;
}
:root {
--page-title-display: block;
}
html {
font-size: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
*, :after, :before {
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, :after, :before {
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the CSS being used around that area (using your browsers dev tools)? That should give some ides of for example the width of the elements holding the titles. We'd need to see some of that code in order to help.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. I did this, though I can't decipher it much on my own yet.  I edited the post to contain the CSS I found.

Comment: @AHaworth is the CSS I posted above what you were looking for? Thanks for the help!:)

Comment: Hi, not this doesn't look like it, it looks more like the start of styling. Do you have a link to the site I could look at direct?

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry for the later reply. I do! I have it set to maintenance mode but I can open it up so you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me –

```
.post-navigation__prev--title {
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```